# Are questions about qemu acceptable on unix.se?

Tags: discussion

I wonder which SE community is best suited and accepting of [QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qemu) questions.
Indeed I would think that `superuser` could be another option.
Probably it must depend about how much related to unix/linux the qemu question is?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, exactly: it depends on how "UNIXy" the question is. A question asking about running Windows ME as a guest with Windows 10 as host would be off topic. As a general rule, if the question is about something Unix or Linux, then it is on topic.

So, if either your guest or your host OS is a Unix or Linux ***and the question is about the Unix or Linux side of things***, then it should be on topic. By that I mean that if your question only requires *nix knowledge to answer, it should be on topic. If your question requires changing settings or configuring a non-nix OS (be that the guest or the host) then Super User is probably a better choice.